How to create ram and rom section IDA?
I have a binary linker descriptor for preloader.bin
ENTRY(_start)

romBase = 0x00201000;
bss1Base = 0x00102000;
bss2Base = 0x00267000;
stackBase = 0x00200000;

/* log_sram_buf + bss1 should be less than 40 KB.*/
MEMORY {
    bss1 : ORIGIN = 0x00102000, LENGTH = 0xBC00
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00201000, LENGTH = 0x3A000
    bss2 : ORIGIN = 0x00267000, LENGTH = 0x14000
    stack : ORIGIN = 0x00200000, LENGTH = 0xC00
}

The file is the firmware for an arm device. I think the binary might contain the proprietary header. So I am trying to find the entry point of the actual code.
